# JavaScript setInterval callback function called unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to extend function using prototype and I want to call extended function using `setInterval` function.

```
var test = function(){};
testProto = test.prototype;

testProto.a = function(){
    return this;
}

testProto.b = function(){
    return this;
}
var idx = 0;
testProto.c = function(){
    console.log('call -> ' + (idx++))
    var self = this;
    setInterval(self.c.bind(self) , 1000)
}


var test = new test();
test.a().b().c();
```

### My Expectation:

> first call : call ->  1
>
> second call : call ->  2
>
> third call : call ->  3

### Result:

> first call : call ->  1
>
> second call : call ->  2 , call -> 3
>
> second call : call ->  4 , call -> 5 , call -> 6 , call -> 7

What I was wrong? How to fix it and how to make result I expected.

Comment: `c()` creates an interval that calls c() ... which creates an interval that calls c() ... which creates an interval that calls c() ... etc ... new interval created every second, after 10 seconds you'll have a thousand intervals, after twenty you'll have over a million ...

Comment: ah~ i got it! you mean before i clear setInterval function, it never die.. and somewhere it keep calling c()... right?

Comment: you never clear the interval, so I don't understand your sentence

Comment: sorry my english. but understand what you said.  it is like a fractal tree. my solution is using setTimeout funtion.